# Android connect using WPS

Tags: android, wifi

in my app i can connect to a wifi network using the presharedkey without any problems.
And my Phone (Galaxy Nexus) is able to connect via WPS in wifi-network-settings.

But now I am trying to connect to a wifi network using the WPS pin method. (enter pin on device)
I googled alot and found "android.net.wifi.WpsInfo" 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WpsInfo.html

Whith this i am able to set up the WPS-settings, but how can i use this to connect to a wifi network?

I started programming android-apps just a few days ago,
could someone with a bit more experience & knowledge help me, pleas?

(I am using api15, Android 4.0.3)

Comment: It took me to figure out how to connect using the settings interface (not programmatically).  The trick is to press the menu button on the list of available networks, at least on Android 4.x.  You could probably find the source code for the settings application and look at that, as one of the options is to use a PIN.